# Multibit validation error message

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, multibit, error

Ok guys now i'm having a new problem. I'm trying to send my bitcoins to another wallet and I keep getting this error message saying "Validation error". The bitcoins are in my wallet and my transaction has been confirmed for a week now. But I can't send my bitcoins. Help?